# Как обрезать n символов с конца строки в столбце pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, datetime

Есть датафрейм со столбцом Time, для корректной дальнейшей обработки
время нужно удалить а дату оставить. Как это сделать?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QHhZa9jO3MN6vCjFa2Up_uMhMdL3R3ou/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Какой тип данных вы хотите получить в итоге для столбца `Time` / `Период` ?

Comment: переведите его в тип datetime и df.colname.dt.date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

исходный DF:

```
filename = r"D:\download\7754_0502.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

---

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
     КоличествоОборот КоличествоКонечныйОстаток СуммаОборот               Период
0                 337                       337    4 290,32   01.07.2017 0:00:01
1                  -3                       334      -38,19   03.07.2017 0:00:00
2                 -10                       324     -127,31   04.07.2017 0:00:00
3                 -15                       309     -190,96   04.07.2017 0:00:00
4                  -2                       307      -25,46   04.07.2017 0:00:00
...               ...                       ...         ...                  ...
1355               -3                        71       -21,2  30.12.2019 15:13:32
1356              -22                        49     -155,47  09.01.2020 12:00:00
1357              -15                        34        -106  09.01.2020 12:00:01
1358               -9                        25       -63,6  09.01.2020 12:00:02
1359               -2                        23      -14,14  10.01.2020 11:23:05

[1360 rows x 4 columns]
```

**решение для строкового типа данных:**

```
col = "Период"
df[col] = df[col].str.split().str[0]
```

---

```
In [40]: df
Out[40]:
     КоличествоОборот КоличествоКонечныйОстаток СуммаОборот      Период
0                 337                       337    4 290,32  01.07.2017
1                  -3                       334      -38,19  03.07.2017
2                 -10                       324     -127,31  04.07.2017
3                 -15                       309     -190,96  04.07.2017
4                  -2                       307      -25,46  04.07.2017
...               ...                       ...         ...         ...
1355               -3                        71       -21,2  30.12.2019
1356              -22                        49     -155,47  09.01.2020
1357              -15                        34        -106  09.01.2020
1358               -9                        25       -63,6  09.01.2020
1359               -2                        23      -14,14  10.01.2020

[1360 rows x 4 columns]
```

**решение для типа данных `datetime64`:**

```
col = "Период"
df = pd.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=[col])

df[col] = df[col].dt.floor("D")
```

---

```
In [45]: df
Out[45]:
     КоличествоОборот КоличествоКонечныйОстаток СуммаОборот     Период
0                 337                       337    4 290,32 2017-01-07
1                  -3                       334      -38,19 2017-03-07
2                 -10                       324     -127,31 2017-04-07
3                 -15                       309     -190,96 2017-04-07
4                  -2                       307      -25,46 2017-04-07
...               ...                       ...         ...        ...
1355               -3                        71       -21,2 2019-12-30
1356              -22                        49     -155,47 2020-09-01
1357              -15                        34        -106 2020-09-01
1358               -9                        25       -63,6 2020-09-01
1359               -2                        23      -14,14 2020-10-01

[1360 rows x 4 columns]


In [46]: df.dtypes
Out[46]:
КоличествоОборот                     object
КоличествоКонечныйОстаток            object
СуммаОборот                          object
Период                       datetime64[ns]   #  <---- NOTE !
dtype: object
```